# How do I hide this element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

Here's the html code rendered in the browser. I want to hide the `div.embed` element:

```
<div id='video_div'>
<img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/fTWpHknumdg/hqdefault.jpg" style="width: 200px; ">
<div class="embed">
<object width="300" height="194">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fTWpHknumdg?version=3">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/fTWpHknumdg?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="194" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque">
</object>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the js code I'm running now. This doesn't work for me. However it seems to work in the jsfiddle provided by the first answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:300,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ 
    $("#video_div").prepend($("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 }));
});

$('div.embed').hide();
});
```

Could it be that the hide code is being called after the element is loaded? How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to hide??  Perhaps include an HTML snippet of the elements you're trying to work on.

Comment: Ok I posted the HTML that my browser sees. Btw, note that I did try: `$('div.embed').hide();` That doesn't work. I want to just hide the embedded video. If I do `$('#video_id').hide();` the whole div does hide, but I don't want to hide the image in that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to use Javascript to hide the DIV? Much simpler to do it with CSS

```
div.embed { display: none; }
```

**Update**

```
$("#SomeElement").click(function() {
   $("div.embed").toggle();
});
```

The CSS will take care of the initial state; the Javascript code will enable hiding/showing the DIV's thereafter.

Comment: why doesn't this js code work?  `$("#video_div img").click(function() {
    $("div.embed").toggle();
 });`

Comment: I did add that CSS styling, but the video does not appear when I click the thumbnail :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuNvs/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div.embed').hide(); 
});
```

And this works fine. Perhaps the hide code is being called before element is loaded into the DOM?

Comment: how would I know if that were the case? I just posted the js code I'm using now. Is it wrong in any way?

Comment: come to think of it, that seems to be the only possible explanation. How do I get the hide code to be called after the element is loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure the details of the embedly API, but probably you can add the .hide() inside of the callback function, after the prepend.

Answer (score 0):

Try Chaining them together.  So something like this (use children() to find the inner div:

```
$('a.oembed').embedly(
  {maxWidth:300,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', 
    function(e, oembed){ 
      $("#video_div").prepend($("<img>", {
        src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width:200 })).children("div.embed").hide();
});
```

If it is always suppose to be hidden then just do it via css.

**Update:**

Try using .[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) in `$(document).ready()`:

```
$('div.embed').load(function() {
  $('div.embed').hide();
});
```

This will fire once the element and everything within it is loaded.

Comment: actually never mind, sorry! I thought it worked but I was using a video with a bigger thumbnail that covered the video. The video was still there...

Comment: The load function is tied to the element loading.  So once an element and everything in it (all of it's children) are loaded, everything within .load() fires.  Without knowing what exactly the thumb is used for I'm not sure what you're asking.  Was it a temporary place holder?

Comment: What I'm doing is showing the thumbnail right away with the video hidden, and then when a user clicks the thumbnail, it disappears and the video appears. So I need to initially only have the thumbnail display without the video.